# create a scatterplot with x axis coming from one dataset and y axis coming from a second dataset and colour the points according to the dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot

i have two dataframes comtaining results from epigenetic analysis.

the column from df1 which is important to the plot is labelled beta_ADHD
the column from df2 which is important to the plot is labelled beta_ADHD

I would like to make the the column from df 1 the x axis and the column from df 2 the y axis,
i would also like to label the points on the graph according to the data set they are from.

this is what ive tried so far but nothing has worked yet:

```
ggp <- ggplot(NULL, aes(Beta_ADHD, Beta_ADHD)) +    # Draw ggplot2 plot based on two data frames
    geom_point(data = df1, col = "red") +
    geom_point(data = df2, col = "blue")
ggp                                 # Draw plot
```

and i also tried this:

```
ggplot(data=data.frame(x=df1$Beta_ADHD, y=df2$Beta_ADHD), aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
```

I'm at a complete loss here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to combine the inputs into a single data frame in order to use them as co-ordinates for a scatter plot. (Also, the 2 data sets must have the same number of values.)

I don't believe it makes sense to label or colour the points according to which data set they are from. As we are taking the x-coordinate from df1 and the y-coordinate from df2, that means that every point comes from both data sets. It is the labels on the x-axis `beta_ADHD1` and y-axis `beta_ADHD2` that show which data set the value came from. You can change the text and color of the axis titles using `xlab()`, `ylab()` and `theme()`.

```
# create some sample data
df1 <- data.frame(beta_ADHD=runif(100,0,10))
df2 <- data.frame(beta_ADHD=rnorm(100,0,10))

# create a new data frame containing the required co-ordinates
# the values from df1 are named beta_ADHD1 and the values from df2 are named beta_ADHD2
new_df <- data.frame(beta_ADHD1 = df1$beta_ADHD, beta_ADHD2 = df2$beta_ADHD) 

# plot this data using ggplot
ggplot(new_df, aes(x = beta_ADHD1, y = beta_ADHD2)) + geom_point() + 
  xlab('beta_ADHD from df1') + ylab('beta_ADHD from df2') +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(color ='red'), axis.title.y = element_text(color = 'blue'))
```

[image]